# How do you create a javascript class with immutable properties

Tags: javascript, class, properties, immutability

This question is specifically about preventing unwanted properties from being added to a javascript "class". I have a class called Animal.

```
function Animal(){
this.name="";
this.type="";
//20 other properties
}
```

What would be the easiest way for a user to create their own Animal and add 20 properties. I want to also prevent the user from accidentally adding incorrect properties.

my current method:

```
    var myAnimal= new Animal();
    myAnimal.name="fluffy";
    myAnimal.type="cat";
    myAnimal.typo="cat";
```

//adding 20 more properties would require typing myAnimal 20 more times 
Plus if a user makes a typo it would add it as a new property.

I was hoping there would be something like this:

```
myAnimal=new Animal{
name:"fluffy",
type:"cat";
typo:"cat" //would throw an error
}
```

I've looked into Object.freeze Object.seal, Object.preventExtensions but not sure how they apply to classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `Object.seal(this)` at the end of the constructor to prevent new properties from being added:

```
function Animal() {
    this.name = "";
    this.type = "";
    // 20 other properties
    Object.seal(this);
}
```

and you can take an object with initial values in the constructor:

```
function Animal(initial) {
    this.name = "";
    this.type = "";
    // 20 other properties
    Object.seal(this);
    Object.assign(this, initial);
}
```

used like so:

```
myAnimal = new Animal({
    name: "fluffy",
    type: "cat",
    typo: "cat",
});
```

with the downside that the error doesn’t point directly at `typo` like it would if you used multiple assignment statements.

Comment: In your second example, I am surprised that you can call `Object.assign()` *after* `Object.seal()`.

Comment: @kevinarpe: `Object.seal()` stops *new* properties from being added while keeping existing ones writable. You might be thinking of `Object.freeze()`, which makes the object entirely read-only.

Comment: *Hat tip*!  I was confused.  Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) For this.
You can set custom setter, what throw an Error when obj does not has the property.
You can do the same with `get` too in that case no more `undefined` cause of typo.

```js
function Animal() {
    this.name = "";
    this.type = "";
    
    return new Proxy(this, {
        set: function(obj, prop, value) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            {
                throw Error("I don`t have this property: " + prop);
            }
            obj[prop] = value;
        }
    });
}

var cat = new Animal();
console.log(cat);
cat.name = "Rita";
console.log(cat);
cat.nama = "Rata";
console.log(cat);
```

Comment: This is a very useful example of how to check for a property. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for pointing out an object I wasn't even aware of. [This post](http://thecodebarbarian.com/thoughts-on-es6-proxies-performance) suggests that proxies are quite slow but concludes that "odds are you won't feel the performance implications unless you've ever found yourself changing promise libraries...for performance reasons".